# Default Proxy ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, proxy, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to configure a default proxy to enable Application Insights.
In an ASP.NET Web Api the default proxy can be set in the web.config like below:

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy proxyaddress="someaddress" bypassonlocal="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

With this setting AI works fine. Unfortunately I could not find an option to set the proxy in appsettings.json. Is there any possibility to define the default proxy in an ASP.NET Core Web API?

Or do I have to configure the proxy in IIS, when the application is getting hosted with it?

**Edit:**
I am setting the default proxy now like this:

```
    WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("someaddress"), true)
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = true
    };
```

When getting the proxy with

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.GetProxy(new Uri("https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track"))
```

it returns the correct proxy.

Strange things happens when Fiddler is running.
As soon as Fiddler is running the application is logging successfully to AI. When closing Fiddler the logging breaks again.

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to configure HttpClient proxy globally?

If so, I am afraid it is impossible. You may consider creating an encapsulate class with accepting Proxy configuration and return a HttpClient, you could load the configuration from appsettings.json or anywhere

Comment: I am not using a HttpClient. Maybe the TelemetryClient is using it to push the logs to Application Insights, but I am not sure about this. Like I said in the edit, the proxy is set now and should not be the problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your traffic is going through Fiddler Proxy so when Fiddler shuts down so as your connection to other services.